# Using Django JSON serializer for object that is not a Model

Tags: python, django, json, google-app-engine, serialization

- Is it possible to use Django serializer without a Model?
- How it is done?
- Will it work with google-app-engine?

I don't use Django framework, but since it is available, I would want to use its resources here and there.
Here is the code I tried:

```
from django.core import serializers
obj = {'a':42,'q':'meaning of life'}
serialised = serializers.serialize('json', obj)
```

this generates an error

```
ERROR ... __init__.py:385] 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 15):

Serializers are only for models. Instead you can use [simplejson](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/) bundled with Django.

```
from django.utils import simplejson
json_str = simplejson.dumps(my_object)
```

Simplejson 2.0.9 docs are [here](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.9/docs/index.html).

Comment: +1: And you can read about simplejson implementation at http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.9/docs/index.html

Comment: What about if someone would want to serialize an object which has a property that's a QuerySet?

Answer (score 0):

The GQLEncoder class in this library can take a db.Model entity and serialize it. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it's been useful to me.