# What's the best way to have value object using Django data model?

Tags: python, json, django-models

Our Django data model objects are nicely mapped to database tables.  We want a way to package data from two or more tables into a customized structure, so that we can easily serve it up as JSON feed, having all the attributes and is in the desired format.

It is kind of like "value objects" (POJO) in other environment such as JAVA, providing convenience when packaging and displaying data.   They should be transient and not persisted in database; yet at the same time contains all the necessary attributes and in the original data types (in Django world this is called "_meta").

Appreciate your reply and suggestions.

Comment: So what is the problem? Simply make a class that contains attributes of these two models as instances.

Comment: Interesting! Any code samples?

Comment: Sounds like what you want to use is Django Rest Framework.

Comment: Appreciated everyone's answers & comments: Aaron, Alex..   5 years ago when I was new to Python, I had pre-conceived notions brought along from Java background; here and now I have had years of direct experience working with python, that original question seems not so relevant.  My appreciation to Alex & Aaron stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work for you?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    field = DoesNotMatter()

class Bar(models.Model):
    field = DoesNotMatter()


class Combined(object):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo_field = foo.field
        self.bar_field = bar.field
```

Comment: Appreciated your suggestion, alex.
After we blended the idea into our following code blocks,
we got the error: 
...
'Composite' object has no attribute '_meta'
...

This was our dilemma: when the data dump has no '_meta',
the resulting JSON contains list of dictionary of key
and value all in str.

On the other hand, a native object like 'Comment' can have
nicer (int and other data types...) looking JSON, like this:[{"pk": 1, "model": "blog.comment", "fields": {"body": "Comments on Craps", "post": 2, "author": "Foo", "created": "2012-03-02 10:39:48"}}]

Comment: *********** models.py ********************

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("%s: %s" % (self.post, self.body[:60]))

Comment: ### value object to test
class Composite(object):

    def __init__(self, post, comment):
        self.post_title = post.title
        self.post_body = post.body
 self.post_created = post.created
 
 if comment:
     self.comment_created = comment.created
     self.comment_author = comment.author
     self.comment_body = comment.body
 else:
     pass

Comment: ************** views.py *****************

def list_composites(request):
    stylish_data = []
    N = 10
    date_N_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
    raw_data = Post.objects.filter(created__gte=date_N_days_ago)
    for post in raw_data:
 try:
            latest_comment = post.comment_set.latest('created')
 except Comment.DoesNotExist:
     latest_comment = None
        my_instance = Composite(post, latest_comment)
        stylish_data.append(my_instance)

    data = serializers.serialize("json", stylish_data)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")

Comment: the answer to this question suggests to use simplejson instead of djangos serializer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005422/using-django-json-serializer-for-object-that-is-not-a-model

Answer (score 0):

Once I dropped the notion of Value Object carried over from JAVA background,
and started to focus on what I really want, I found a simple way to get
this: to custom build a dictionary in views.py, based on the data
coming back from related models.   And then add each dictionary to 
a list bucket and use json dumps prior to rendering JSON feeds.